# Xamarin: Binding a ContentView content not working, wrong implementation

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, binding

I need help understanding how I can bind a ContentView's Content's to my Xamarin page. I have tried maybe 20 different methods and I can only get the binded contentview to render when I don't use bindings and set the property directly.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="GridLayout" RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="60" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <nav:NavView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Padding="0,0,0,0" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                      HeightRequest="60" x:Name="nav"/>
        <ContentView BindingContext="{Binding MainView}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

and then below is my code behind

```
public partial class DetailLayoutView : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
    private ContentView mainView;
    public ContentView MainView
    {
        get { return mainView; }
        set
        {
            mainView = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MainView");
        }
    }

    public DetailLayoutView()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        MainView = new PyxusChatView();
        BindingContext = MainView;
    }
}
```

Can someone help guide me to the right direction? I dont have the bandwidth to implement an entire MVVM refactor at this time I would just like to know how I can achieve this w/ minimal code.

Comment: I am able to get the below code to work, although for the sake of education for the community I will leave this unanswered as it doesnt exactly resolve the "set binding" issue, but does get the job done.....    public ContentView MainView
        {
            get { return mainView; }
            set
            {
                mainView = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MainView");
                test.Content = value.Content;
            }
        }

Comment: With all due respect this code is broken at a very fundamental level, I don't think you're quite understanding the MVVM pattern. You're supposed to bind Views to View Models, what you've got here is a View (DetailLayoutView) binding to one of it's own properties (something very rarely needed), which happens to be of type ContentView, which you're then trying to assign to another view (PyxusChatView). This is not MVVM, and you will have all manner of problems such as the one you have now if you continue down this path.

Comment: You are correct, The code is which i've been handed and I've been forced to find hacks, to meet a do or die deadline in 5 days. The manner of problems you're probably referering to is that fact that ContentView does not have any view lifecycle methods... meaning how am I supposed to render UI before making API calls? I beleive after many days of research I was one of the few to accomplish this. Although it is a hack, and going againts the grain, with the hand i've been delt this was the best option, maybe helpful to some others in an odd situation...

Comment: FYI, Once I have more time I will convert over to MVVM and use SQLite to renderer element -pre-api-respone to make app quick as possible, but sometimes as developers we must work as quick as possible to sustain a company

Answer (score 0):

DETECT WHEN A UI IS RENDERED IOS & ANDROID BELOW...

```
public DetailLayoutView()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        MainContentArea.LayoutChanged += MainContentArea_LayoutChanged;
    }

    private void MainContentArea_LayoutChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
           //UI Is now visible, send a msg to let everyone subscribed to "UpdateDetailView" event now that the
           //detail page was changed and it is now okay to make API calls!
           MessagingCenter.Send<ContentView, string>(MainView, "UpdateDetailView", "From BlePairingViewModel");
       });
    }
```

YOU HAVE SENT MSG NOW YOU CAN MAKE API CALLS & YOUR UI IS VISIBLE W/O MVVM... ALTHOUGH MVVM WOULD BE A BETTER PRACTICE TO INDIVIDUALS W/ MORE TIME TO CODE..

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ContentView, string>("Pyx", "UpdateDetailView", (sender, arg) =>
        {
            if (sender == this)
            {
                Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    await OnAppearing();
                });
            }
        });
```

I AM NOT ADVISING THIS AS BEST PRACTICE BUT IT DOES ANSWER THE QUESTION

Comment: Anyone reading this post should be advised that Mark Fledman's response is true best practice.